# Continue tasks when current task is completed

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I have a 25 tasks created in a list. I can fire only 10 threads at time .

I need to do a foreach of my list and start the first 10 tasks using TPL. Then I would like to wait until any tasks completed. If any of the task is completed then I  need to continue my foreach loop and start my 11th task. Similarly I need to do all for 25 tasks in my list.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what are you doing and why? Why can't you use `Parallel.ForEach()` instead of `Task`s?

Comment: Or TPL Dataflow. I find dataflow is often a good approach whenever the OP has concerns around throttling (it usually indicates a pipeline/mesh scenario).

Answer (score 0):

This is a common requirement. The .NET Framework does not contain a perfect solution built-in. A good way to do this is to create a wrapper for all those tasks that awaits a `SemaphoreSlim`. The semaphore will enforce your desired concurrency limit. After awaiting it you can create ans start the real task that you want to run.

This solution can be easily achieved using built-in tools but it has the disadvantage that you have to start all 25 tasks at once. So you cannot process a very big or infinite stream of work items with this technique. Does not seem to be the problem in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at implementing with a BlockingCollection with the size of 10 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx

Comment: I think that's not enough, you should explain how exactly would you use `BlockingCollection`.